# What is needed for @TestHTTPEndpoint to work?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have a unit test annotated with @QuarkusTest. There I want to inject two url's using @TestHTTPEndpoint like this:

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@QuarkusTestResource(MockWorkerResource.class)
@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class)
public class DispatcherTest {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @TestHTTPEndpoint(DispatcherRestApi.class)
    URL dispatcherUrl;

    @TestHTTPEndpoint(WorkerRestApi.class)
    URL workerUrl;
```

DispatcherRestApi and WorkerRestApi are both interfaces annotated with @RegisterRestClient. However injecting these values doesn't work, both will be null. If I add @TestHTTPResource then both will contain "http://localhost:8081/" which is the expected value for dispatcherUrl which is the api implemented by the service being tested.

WorkerRestApi is implemented by a mock service which is started as a QuarkusTestResource and url for it is returned from the lifecyclemanager:

```
public class MockWorkerResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MockWorkerResource.class);

    NettyJaxrsServer netty;

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        logger.info("Starting mock worker server");

        ResteasyDeployment rd = new ResteasyDeploymentImpl();
        rd.setActualResourceClasses(Arrays.asList(MockWorker.class));

        netty = new NettyJaxrsServer();
        netty.setDeployment(rd);
        int port = 9090; //TestPortProvider.getPort();
        netty.setPort(port);
        netty.setRootResourcePath("");
        netty.setSecurityDomain(null);
        netty.start();
        return Map.of("quarkus.rest-client.\"com.foo.bar.common.api.worker.WorkerRestApi\".url", "http://localhost:" + port + "/");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (netty != null) {
            netty.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(TestInjector testInjector) {
        testInjector.injectIntoFields(
            this.netty,
            new AnnotatedAndMatchesType(InjectMockServer.class, NettyJaxrsServer.class)
        );
    }
}
```

I.e. I use an embedded Jaxrs server that instanciates a mock which implements the api. This works much better than e.g. WireMock as I couldn't find a way to maintain a state in the mock there.

My current workaround is to retrieve the properties instead which works but is less fancy:

```
String dispatcherPort = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("quarkus.http.test-port", String.class);
String dispatcherUrlString = "http://localhost:" + dispatcherPort;
logger.infov("dispatcherUrlString: {0}", dispatcherUrlString);
String workerUrlString = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("quarkus.rest-client.\"com.limetransit.fileencoder.common.api.worker.WorkerRestApi\".url", String.class);
logger.infov("workerUrlString: {0}", workerUrlString);
```

Sidenote 1: I tried to use a callback implementing QuarkusTestBeforeClassCallback but there no values are injected at all.

Sidenote 2: The above method to use an embedded Jaxrs server doesn't work with the reactive resteasy implementation. If using the Undertow variant a classloading issue make it not find serializers for datatypes, if using Netty variant then it fails due to an unimplemented method in RuntimeDelegate.

Comment: `@TestHTTPResource` for JAX-RS server endpoints, not REST Client endpoints. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My understanding was that @TestHTTPResource would give the url that the client shall connect to during the tests.

Comment: That is not the case